# Run a query if directed to page

Tags: php, mysql

I am running the following select statement:

```
$oid = ("SELECT DISTINCT (MAX(OrderID)) FROM orders WHERE Username = ". $_SESSION['Username'] ." ");
```

This returns the value of highest Order ID linked to that Username, therefore it being their last order. I want to then run this query:

```
$Query = "update orders set Status = 'Failed' where Status = 'Success' and where OrderID = ". $oid ." ";
```

Which will update the orders table, setting the Status to Failed (where it's currently Success).

Why is $oid, returning nothing? If I manually input the values and run it via PHPMyAdmin it works fine.

```
if (strpos($url,'order-failed') !== false) {
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT (MAX(OrderID)) FROM orders WHERE Username = '". $_SESSION['Username'] ."' ";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['OrderID']; // For Debugging
    echo "<br /><br />";

    $Query = "UPDATE orders SET Status = 'Failed' WHERE Status = 'Success' and OrderID = ". $oid ." ";
    $mysqli->query($Query);
    echo $Query; // For Debugging
}
```

The echos return:
SELECT DISTINCT (MAX(OrderID)) FROM orders WHERE Username = 'email@email.com'
UPDATE orders SET Status = 'Failed' WHERE Status = 'Success' and OrderID =

Order ID is blank! :(

Comment: `$oid = (...)` does not run the query. You just create a variable with the query in it.

Comment: $mysqli->query($oid); I have that below the query.

Comment: BTW: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/4193263). To fix this critical security hole, use Prepared Statements.

Comment: Once it's working, I'll fix up any vulnerabilities. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Can you add more of the code that you have? From what I understand mysql->query will return a result that contains the value that you want. You need to extract the values from it. Check out the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: I don't see the code where you're setting `$oid` to anything else than a String which is a SQL query. Inside the `if`, where you run the query,  you're justing echoeing the `OrderID` but not setting `$oid`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

`$oid`is returning nothing because it is not a function/method, it's a variable of type string (implicitly). Why would you expect a string to 'return' something?

As for your second query, of course `$oid` is empty. You're not assigning anything to it before. Weren't you supposed to assign the result of the first query to the variable so you could use that orderID (oid) in the second query? Do it!

Comment: Markus, judging by this comment I have $oid stored as a variable which equates to the Query I am running, therefore I would then need to somehow pull out the number returns i.e. 5 and then save that as a variable?

Comment: As I said: The question is "what do you do with `$oid`? You need to show us how you run the query! Paste more code!

Comment: Ok, let me explain. I have this code to say if you are on order-failed.php, select the OrderID from orders where the Username is equal to $_SESSION['Username']. Then, it grabs the OrderID as a number i.e. if it's order 9 I have "9" as a value then I run another statement to Update orders where the OrderID is equal to $oid...

Comment: Don't post your code here in the comments, edit your question to show your WHOLE code where you fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to use `WHERE` twice:

   > UPDATE orders set Status = 'Failed' where Status = 'Success' and **<s>where</s>** OrderID = ". $oid
2. Prefer to use the `AS` keyword in complex querys:

   ```sql
   SELECT DISTINCT (MAX(OrderID)) AS highest_order_id FROM orders WHERE Username = ...
   ```
3. Do you fetch the result of the query?

   ```
   $result = $mysqli->query($oid);
   $row0 = $result->fetch_assoc();
   $highest_order_id = $row0["highest_order_id"];

   $Query = "UPDATE orders SET Status = 'Failed' " . 
            "WHERE Status = 'Success' AND OrderID = ". $highest_order_id ." ";
   ```

**Please notice that my sample code is still vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/4193263)!**

Answer (score 0):

> Why is $oid, returning nothing?

First, check for errors:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($oid);
if (!$result)
{
  echo("Error description: " . $mysqli->error);
}
```

Then, check the data.

```
// Query
echo $oid;
// Result
echo $result->num_rows;
```

It could very well be that you query is simply not returning anything (no error) and then you should be able to spot it in the query.

Comment: This is very helpful, however - I have no error apparently! If I run the query manually via PHPMyAdmin it brings back the value I require which is strange.

Comment: Then I'm quite certain that the queries are not identical.